# Temporary ArrayList to create a new one

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, adapter

I know the title sounds weird but I have to rebuild an `ArrayList`. Therefore I save the ArrayList Items into another temporary `ArrayList`.

Then I clear the ArrayList that needs to be rebuilt, and then the rebuilding process starts. My code looks like following:

```
ArrayList<ListData> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(int i = 0; i<data.size();i++){
                                String name = data.get(i).getName();
                                Log.e("name: ", name);
                                String number = String.valueOf(i);
                                Log.e("number: ", number);
                                String uri = data.get(i).getUri();
                                Log.e("uri: ", uri);
                                listData.setName(name);
                                listData.setNumber(number);
                                listData.setUri(uri);
                                tempList.add(listData);
                            }
                        data.clear();
                        for(int i=0; i<tempList.size(); i++){
                                String name = tempList.get(i).getName();
                                Log.e("getName: ", name);
                                String number = String.valueOf(i);
                                Log.e("getNumber: ", number);
                                String uri = tempList.get(i).getUri();
                                Log.e("getUri: ", uri);
                                listData.setName(name);
                                listData.setNumber(number);
                                listData.setUri(uri);
                                data.add(listData);
                        }
```

The code works without any errors but the result is wrong, here are the log outputs. You should see what the problem is:

> <12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/name:: Bonita (feat. J Balvin)
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/number:: 0
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/uri:: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A68
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/name:: Que Va
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/number:: 1
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/uri:: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A67
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/name:: Que Va
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/number:: 2
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/uri:: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A67
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/getName:: Que Va
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/getNumber:: 0
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/getUri:: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A67
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/getName:: Que Va
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/getNumber:: 1
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/getUri:: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A67
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/getName:: Que Va
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/getNumber:: 2
>   12-22 08:36:55.281 5023-5023/com.example.enesakbulut.fitness E/getUri:: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A67

As you see it saves the different names and numbers in the correct way to the tempList (Arraylist), but when I try to get them from the tempList I just get the same item over and over. Same name, same number and same uri. The code is so simple, I just can not believe this causes problems.

I hope you can help me out! :)

Comment: Can you put a break point at data.clear and debug your application. Check if your temp arraylist contains the right data

Comment: This would be hard for us to figure out, but you should be able to figure out the issue with a debugger.

Comment: @Nero just found out, that the size of the temporary ArrayList is 1 instead of 3. But I don't understand why... At least, I found out the reason for the wrong output but I really don't know how to fix it...

Comment: So at this stage what is the problem? The output is the same? If that's the case, have you tried the answer provided by Rainmaker?

Comment: @Nero Yes. Thank you for your help too. It fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating new instances of ListData to add to new array, if ListData is your pojo class this code should work;

```
ArrayList<ListData> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(int i = 0; i<data.size();i++){
                                String name = data.get(i).getName();
                                Log.e("name: ", name);
                                String number = String.valueOf(i);
                                Log.e("number: ", number);
                                String uri = data.get(i).getUri();
                                Log.e("uri: ", uri);
                                ListData listData = new ListData();
                                listData.setName(name);
                                listData.setNumber(number);
                                listData.setUri(uri);
                                tempList.add(listData);
                            }
                        data.clear();
                        for(int i=0; i<tempList.size(); i++){
                                String name = tempList.get(i).getName();
                                Log.e("getName: ", name);
                                String number = String.valueOf(i);
                                Log.e("getNumber: ", number);
                                String uri = tempList.get(i).getUri();
                                Log.e("getUri: ", uri);
                                ListData listData = new ListData();
                                listData.setName(name);
                                listData.setNumber(number);
                                listData.setUri(uri);
                                data.add(listData);
                        }
```

Comment: you must add new object to your array with new values

Comment: Thank you so much :) It fixed the "problem"